# GCP open a firewall port works on 30000, but not on 3400

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

I enabled 2 firewall rules on GCP for ports 30000 and 3400. The rules are the same, just the ports are different. Still, only the 30000 is allowed. What I am missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Both ports are open on the server as I can see them and connect to them them locally:

```
netstat -tlnp
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::3400                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:3333          :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::30000                :::*                    LISTEN      -

nc -zvw10 localhost 3400
Connection to localhost 3400 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

nc -zvw10 localhost 30000
Connection to localhost 30000 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

But remotelly, only the 30000 port is available.

nc -zvw10 xx.xx.xxx.xxx 3400
nc: connectx to xx.xx.xxx.xxx port 3400 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out

UPDATE:
Interesting, it seems that the 30000 port translated itself in an IP table rule on both vm instance, but the 3400 port did not. allow-30000 rule is indeed a few month older, while allow-3400 was created yesterday.

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:30000
```

Comment: looks to me like you're missing nothing? I'd ask gcp customer support

Comment: Are you in an organisation with hierarchical firewall rule? Did you try the network analyzer to diagnostic the connectivity? https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/network-analyzer/overview

Comment: Repeat your test but change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. If that fails, your process is only listening on IPv6 for connections.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere No. It's a basic personal GCP account with 2 vm instances. I don't have access to Network Analysis

Comment: @JohnHanley Connection to 127.0.0.1 3400 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

Comment: As a temporary fix I've manually added the iptables rule allowing connections to port 3400: `sudo iptables -A ufw-user-input -s 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp --dport 3400 -j ACCEPT`. I am  still not sure why the rule from GCP UI didn't propagate to the VMs iptable.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Be default, most GCP versions do not have `iptables` enabled. Did you enable `iptables` previously? VPC Firewall rules do not modify `iptables` configurations.

Comment: @JohnHanley I use an Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I didn't enable `iptables` myself. Maybe there was a change on how VPC Firewall rules work?

Comment: Does the firewall rule have the same priority? Can you double check the network tags of both vm instance and compare and make sure that these network tags are the same in your firewall rule. I suggest enabling flow logs in the rule of port 3400 this might also help you identify what is blocking the traffic. Lastly, perform a connectivity test, you can use this [link](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/how-to/running-connectivity-tests#vm-to-non-cloud) as a guidance.

Comment: @YvanG. Tags and priorities are the same. Blocking was caused by some `iptables` rules as I explained in the question update

Answer (score 1):

@dcernahoschi I agree with @johnhanley VPC firewall rule do not modify iptables. There must be any configuration changes from the VM under iptables since they are not configured at the same time. I believe the best way to explain this is that the VPC Firewall is working at the project level while the IPtables works at the OS level.

Adding IPtables rules allowing connection to port 3400 is not actually a temporary fix but it is the solution. I found this [documentation](https://medium.com/skilluped/what-is-iptables-and-how-to-use-it-781818422e52) that explains more about IPtables and how it works at an OS level, this also have a little overview about firewall. Also sharing an overview of [GCP's Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/firewall/docs/firewalls) on how it works on a project level.